# New node is lagging behind the old one

Tags: stellar-core, scp

Hi I was doing some experiment (especially after the news of stellar network going down) in my simple 2 nodes private network and got some confusion.
Here are the steps I follow:

1. Configured network with 2 nodes, both of them are validators and are included into each others quorum sets with theshold of 50% like this:

```
[QUORUM_SET]
THRESHOLD_PERCENT=50
VALIDATORS=[
    "$node01",
    "$node02"
]
```

2. I stopped the 1st node for some time - the SCP still works with a 2nd node only, since the THRESHOLD_PERCENT was 50 (1 out of 2)
3. Restarted the 1st node - it started catching up with the 2nd node.
4. But what I am seeing is they both are running on different ledger state like the 1st node is trailing 2nd node. I was expecting that after some time they both should work on same slot but 1st one is always lagging behind.

What am I missing in concepts ?

EDIT: 1st node is always in `"state" : "Catching up","status" : [ "Catching up: Waiting: catchup" ]` state. Also none of transaction works on 1st node.

Comment: Check your logs. What's your history config? Can 1st one acces the history archive of the 2nd one?

Comment: Hey @sui sorry for the late reply. And thanks for the suggestion. that is what I doing wrong. I fixed the history `get` of node 1 to point to node2's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So fixed this problem. My node1's `get` in `history` was not pointing to the node2's archive path. After setting them properly it worked.

Node1's history configuration

```
[HISTORY.local]
get="cp /tmp/stellar-core/node02/history/vs/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} /tmp/stellar-core/node01/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p /tmp/stellar-core/node01/history/vs/{0}"
```

Node2's history configuration

```
[HISTORY.local]
get="cp /tmp/stellar-core/node01/history/vs/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} /tmp/stellar-core/node02/history/vs/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p /tmp/stellar-core/node02/history/vs/{0}"
```

Comment: Side note: on most systens /tmp will be cleared on reboot and is therefore not a good location. Better move it to somewhere else.

Comment: yeah agreed. thanks

Comment: Glad you solved it! Would you be able to accept this answer? Then it won't keep showing up on the front page. Thanks!